# Puppeteer TimeoutError: Race Condition of FileChooser and Click

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

There seems to be a race condition between "waitForFileChooser" and "click" when I try to automate uploading files according to the puppeteer's documentation of API.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, so how can I solve this issue?

TimeoutError: waiting for file chooser failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded.

```
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForFileChooser(),
  page.click('#upload-file-button'), // a button that triggers file selection
]);
await fileChooser.accept(['someFile.pdf']);
```

Comment: What site are you running this on? Can you provide a [mcve] of some HTML that fails? Because this code is straight from the docs, so if it's problematic, it might be worth opening an issue (I suspect there is something else going on with your particular use case, though).

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the timeout for `waitForFileChooser` (see https://pub.dev/documentation/puppeteer/latest/puppeteer/Page/waitForFileChooser.html):

```js
// ...
page.waitForFileChooser({timeout: 50000}),
// ...
```